# How to get workflow instance's Title/Name property using WorkflowServicesManager in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, custom-actions, visual-studio-2013, workflow-manager

I am trying to iterate, all the workflow instances belonging to the particular listItem in a custom activity for SharePoint 2013 visual studio custom workflow.

```
WorkflowServicesManager workflowServiceManager  = new WorkflowServicesManager(ctx,oWeb);

var workflowInstancesService = workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService();

var workflowInstances = workflowInstancesService.EnumerateInstancesForListItem(listIDGUID,itemID));

foreach (var instances in workflowInstances)
{
    instances.   -- pls refer the images. 
}
```

There seems to be no property for the workflow Title/Name.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get that name from WorkflowSubscriptionService. This is how you get that.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// get workflow name from instance
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="instance"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetWorkflowName(WorkflowInstance instance)
    {
        var workflowSubscription = WorkflowServicesManager.Current.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService().
                GetSubscription(instance.WorkflowSubscriptionId);
        return workflowSubscription.Name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Properties` property.

```
foreach (var instance in workflowInstances)
{
    var properties = instance.Properties;
}
```

I've never done this before, so to find what properties will be returned for each instance, place a break point on this line and debug. I'm sure you'll find a title/name property there. Then to use it you would do:

```
var propertyValue = properties["property_name"];
```

MSDN reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowservices.workflowinstance_properties.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A completely different approach you could try:

```
var list = oWeb.Lists.GetList(listIDGUID, true);
var item = list.GetItemById(itemID);

foreach (var workflow in item.Workflows)
{
    var workflowName = workflow.ParentAssociation.Name;
}
```